# Sending variables to the controller from the view : Zend Controller

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, view, controller

I want to send a set of variables to the controller from  the view , but apparently they don t come to the controller, already the success function does not repent, here is the code for sending the niveu of view, knowing that the success function m displays nothing :

```
$.ajax({ 

     type: "POST", 
     url: "<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'properties', "action"      =>"tasktodo")); ?>",                  
      data: { 
      latitude: position.coords.latitude, 
      longitude: position.coords.longitude, 
      }, 
      success: function(data) { 
      alert ("datalatit"); 
      } 
      });
```

can someone tell me where is the problem ?

Comment: Please could you provide more info? Is it the latitude and longitude variables that you don't think are being POSTed to the controller? If so, how are you checking this? Are there any javascript errors? Have you checked the networking panel in your browser to see if any data is being posted?

Comment: well i m trying just to send a simple variable  ,instead of latitude..

Answer (score 0):

There could be several problems with your request:

1. Make sure that the `url` is generated correctly. Try via hardcoding it just to see. Also debug the output of: `echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'properties",.....`
2. As @Tim Fountain suggested check if you are sending data (Provided that your request gets through at all)
3. Check if there is something blocking your request? Security, Authentication, etc. ??
4. Implement the [`error` callback of jQuery's $.ajax();](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) It is there to handle errors and any implementation of an AJAX call should have it. An example implementation that would "dump" all variables to the console is:

   ```
   success: function(data) {......},
   error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){console.warn('An error occured!');console.log(jqXHR);console.log(textStatus);console.log(errorThrown);}
   ```

This way you will be able to inspect the error. Then implement something to handle it.

Sorry for the poor format of the code. I had some problem with the editor here..

Comment: Hello
I made a few corrections:
But I have a new problem, I have used ajax to send a variable, the success function works well, ie that the variable has been well sent to the controller, but I can not manage to recover n this variable at the controller.